# A simple Minimization problem 1

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Problem 1
Input:    Minimize[x + (1/x), {x, 0, 2}]
Output:   Minimize[1601/40, {40, 0, 2}]
Issue : online showing right result but in software showing wrong result.

Please give your valuable suggestions. Is there any syntax error in the format.

Comment: `Clear[x]` and try again

Comment: The right syntax is Clear[x]; Minimize[{x + (1/x), 0 < x <= 2}, x]

Comment: See [Lingering Definitions: when calculations go bad](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18562/5478)

Comment: Thank you so much, Carl Woll, Kuba